# For which values of $\lambda$ is it consistent to have exactly $\lambda$ cardinals strictly between $\beth_0$ and $\beth_1$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, set-theory, cardinals

According to the [Wikipedia article on the Continuum Hypothesis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuum_hypothesis), the statement $\aleph_1 = 2^{\aleph_0}$ is independent of ZFC.

I'm curious how *many* distinct cardinals there can be between $\aleph_1$ and $2^{\aleph_0}$, let's call this cardinal $\lambda$.

So, the Continuum Hypothesis holds if and only if $\lambda$ is zero.

$ \lambda = 1 $ if and only if $\aleph_1 = 2^{\aleph_0}$ and, more generally, $\aleph_{(\lambda - 1)} = 2^{\aleph_0}$.

I'm curious what is known about the size of the possible "gap" between $\aleph_0$ and $2^{\aleph_0}$, since most of what I've seen while reading a little about the continuum hypothesis just seems to concern whether a gap exists at all or not.

Comment: This gap can be basically anything, subject to [Konig's restriction re: cofinality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K%C3%B6nig%27s_theorem_(set_theory)) - so e.g. $2^{\aleph_0}=\aleph_\omega$ is not possible but $2^{\aleph_0}=\aleph_{\omega+1}$ and $2^{\aleph_0}=\aleph_{\omega_1}$ are each possible. Additionally, it is consistent with $\mathsf{ZFC}$ that $2^{\aleph_0}$ is a fixed point of the $\aleph$-function - that is, $2^{\aleph_0}=\aleph_\alpha$ for some $\alpha$ such that $\aleph_\alpha=\aleph_{\omega_\alpha}$. Finally, it is relatively consistent that $2^{\aleph_0}$ is weakly inaccessible.

Comment: See also [Easton's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Easton%27s_theorem), which says *(roughly)* that the same sort of flexibility can occur throughout the (regular!) cardinals (singulars are [complicated](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_cardinals_hypothesis)). *(I believe all of this has appeared on MSE before, which is why I'm leaving these comments rather than an answer, incidentally - see e.g. [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2592169/28111), [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3311883/28111), or [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2415670) for starters.*)